# my C++ code cannot handle (a little bit) fast data traffic

Tags: c++, c, qt, sockets, networking

**Background:**

I have the below C++ code that listens UDP packets on port`26009` then outputs the received packets

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    udpSocket.bind(26009); //the port that GUI listens (26009)
    connect(&udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
}


void MainWindow::readyRead(){
    QByteArray datagram;
    do {
      datagram.resize(udpSocket.pendingDatagramSize());
      udpSocket.readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
    } while (udpSocket.hasPendingDatagrams());

    qDebug() << "Message: " << datagram;
}
```

On the client side, here is a C code to `unicast` 20 `udp` packets: hi0, hi1, ... hi19:

```
int main(void){
    int i;
    char msg[5] = {'\0'};
    for(i=0; i<20; i++){
       snprintf(msg, 4, "hi%d", i);
       send_unicast("192.168.5.1", msg, 26009);
       memset(msg, 0, sizeof msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

void  send_unicast(char IPaddr[16], char* message, uint16_t destPort){
       struct sockaddr_in si_other;
       int s, slen = sizeof(si_other);

      if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed - line817\n");
        exit(1);
      }

      memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
      si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
      si_other.sin_port = htons(destPort);

      if (inet_aton(IPaddr, &si_other.sin_addr) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed - line 825\n");
        exit(1);
      }

      if (sendto(s, message, 512, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "sendto() failed - line830\n");
        exit(1);
      }
      close(s);
}
```

I run C++ (Server) and C (client) codes on different Linux devices.

**Problem:**

C code works fine and generates the packets. I can see on Wireshark that the packets are received on receiving end (C++ ).

However, the above C++ code cannot receive (or process) the packets correctly, it is somehow too fast for the code to handle and I see only couple output, e.g.

```
hi5
hi14
```

If the frequency of the transmission is significantly slowed down on the C code (adding `sleep(1)`) then the C++ code outputs the packets fine.

**Question:**

I use the received UDP packets to update some information on the GUI (Qt). I guess that the `slot` causes the slowness, and the code would handle the traffic if I used `pthread` to listen the packets but then how the thread needs to notify the main class so that the GUI can update accordingly?

All in all, how do you recommend to modify C++ code, so that it can handle the fast data traffic and notify GUI to update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your readyRead function of MainWindow, I expect this is going to be a problem: -

```
QByteArray datagram;
do {
      qint64 dSize = udpSocket.pendingDatagramSize();
      datagram.resize(dSize);

      udpSocket.readDatagram(datagram.data(), dSize);
   } while (udpSocket.hasPendingDatagrams());
```

If the first packet of data is, let's say 8 bytes long, you set the QByteArray to 8 bytes and read the data.

While reading 8 bytes, if 6 bytes are received, the second time around that loop you're going to to call resize on the byte array, but this time it's going to reduce it from 8 bytes to 6 and read 6 bytes, throwing away the data you previously read in.

Rather than resizing the QByteArray, I suggest you append the data to it: -

```
QByteArray datagram;
do 
{     datagram.append(udpSocket.pendingDatagramSize());
      udpSocket.readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
}while (udpSocket.hasPendingDatagrams());
```

Comment: Alternatively, move the `qDebug()` output (and the QByteArray) into the body of the loop. I think appending datagrams from UDP doesn't make sense, this is just not a stream protocol and the datagrams are typically separate entities.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, it depends on what the OP wants to actually do with the data. If you just want to print it out, then yes, moving it into the body will be sufficient. Either way, the problem is the same, overwriting data before it being displayed. I have seen UDP used for stream data, particularly with multiplayer games, as it's faster than TCP. Of-course there's then the requirement to control things such as ordering of packets etc.

Comment: if I test it with the append, it shows first couple bytes of the 2 packets and first bytes of rest. In total, it outputs about 15 packets. As Ulrich suggests, if I add qDebug() and QByteArray into the loop, the it outputs 20 packets but only the first bytes. If I keep resize and add qDebug() and QByteArray into the loop then it outputs 20 packets with the all bytes correctly. should I keep the resize or use append?

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer. Does that help?